# Getting coverage from .war-dependency in multi-module-project

Tags: java, unit-testing, war, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have setup a Jacoco-subproject to allow Jacoco to handle multi-module-projects in my maven-project as described [here](http://janejieblog.blogspot.com/2017/12/code-coverage-jacoco-with-maven-multi.html). The Jacoco project depends on all .jar-modules in my project as described in the tutuorial. But this setup only seems to work for .jar-files. Instead of understanding that my .war-project produces a .war-file Jacoco is looking for a .jar.

What do I have to do to make the .war-file to get coverage?

Comment: IMO currently it's incredibly hard to understand/guess your "setup".
Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
And add missing details:
instead of "have setup, ... depends on ... , fails" provide exact example 
and exact commands that you execute, so that others can try the same to reproduce your problem,
instead of "error indicates" copy exact error message,
etc.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this [issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/991) will help.

Just add `<type>war</type>` to the dependency in the dedicated module.

---

but after doing that, I got another error:

> Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]

after add `<packaging>pom</packaging>` to the dedicated module for collecting all test result, jacoco works as usual.